# How to create token-based authentication in laravel 4?

Tags: web-services, authentication, filter, laravel-4

I've been suggested to use token-based authentication, in order to secure my webservices, and to create another filter that verifies tokens, apart from auth. The idea is to use the auth filter for log-in, which I have already done in the backend, and to create a new filter for webservices. Could someone recommend a good tutorial on how to do this, or give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i use, specifically for mobile app web services:
https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Which is an OAuth2 server package for Laravel.  It includes all you need to authenticate, generate / validate tokens, throttle, and protect your endpoints.

The OAuth2 spec has a bit of a learning curve, but is definitely worth it.

Comment: Can you point out a good resource to learn about implementing this package?

Comment: The documentation on the [Github page](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) does a great job of explaining the `authorization code` flow (which is like signing into a site with Facebook), but for mobile apps, i usually use the `client_credentials` / `password` flow along with `refresh token` when needed.  It really depends on your implementation as each grant type serves a specific purpose.  You can check out the [Oauth2 spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) to figure out which one is best for you. Or, you can extend the package and roll your own.